# Facebook - This application does not yet support secure browsing (https)

Tags: facebook, https, facebook-apps

I'm trying to create an app on Facebook and facing some problems about security issues.

I want to know why I can access my app by its id: https://apps.facebook.com/371281253013594/
and I can't by its name:  https://apps.facebook.com/nelsonapp/, when I use the name I get this error message:

"Secure browsing is not supported
This application does not yet support secure browsing (https)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The domain where your application is hosted must be **SSL** certified (**https**) eg: https://my-domain.com/my-app. Else, your app can't be published in facebook.

Btw, in the App Settings you have to give this in the **Secure Canvas URL** too, eg:

Canvas Url: http://my-domain.com/my-app

Secure Canvas Url: https://my-domain.com/my-app

What did you wrote in these settings?

Comment: Sahil, thanks for your answer.

Yes the domain has a SSL certificate, but I forgot to fill the Namespace for my app, now I put xptonelsonapp  (only for tests) and now is working -> https://apps.facebook.com/xptonelsonapp